# How do I join two tables with a one to many relationship without returning the cartesian product?

Tags: mysql, join, datasource, cartesian-product

I want to join INVOICE to LICENSE table.  One license can have multiple invoices.  The only column I have to link these tables is the ClientID. The LICENSE table has this structure: LicenseID, ClientID, LicenseAttributes.  The INVOICE table has this structure: Invoice ID, Line Item, ClientID, InvoiceAmount.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM INVOICE I 

LEFT JOIN LICENSE L

ON I.ClientID = L.ClientID;
```

I get theses INCORRECT results:

```
ClientID A, LicenseID X, InvoiceID 1, LineItem 1

ClientID A, LicenseID X, InvoiceID 2, LineItem 1

ClientID A, LicenseID X, InvoiceID 1, LineItem 2

ClientID A, LicenseID X, InvoiceID 2, LineItem 2

ClientID A, LicenseID Y, InvoiceID 1, LineItem 1

ClientID A, LicenseID Y, InvoiceID 2, LineItem 1
```

The Correct results would be as follows:

```
ClientID A, LicenseID X, InvoiceID 1, LineItem 1

ClientID A, LicenseID X, InvoiceID 1, LineItem 2

ClientID A, LicenseID Y, InvoiceID 2, LineItem 1
```

As you can see, I get repeating information in the INCORRECT results.  Anyone have any help here?

Comment: From what you've stated, your data is just plain broken; the invoice and license tables are not directly related in any manner. ...if you have timestamps in both, something MIGHT be possible.

Comment: You need a direct relationship between license and invoice. If your license table had InvoiceID as a foreign key you would be able to do this, but ClientID is not an appropriate relation.

Comment: Please edit your question an include the sample data used to generate this data.  Also, a SQL Fiddle is a good idea.  You probably have another table, something like `InvoiceLicenses` that actually link the tables.

Comment: I only see one client id column. Your query would return two!?!